# Robolectric says "AndroidManifest.xml not found"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, robolectric

While trying to get Robolectric RC3 to work in Android Studio, I get

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: build/intermediates/bundles/debug/AndroidManifest.xml not found or not a file; it should point to your project's AndroidManifest.xml
at org.robolectric.manifest.AndroidManifest.validate(AndroidManifest.java:120)
at org.robolectric.manifest.AndroidManifest.getResourcePath(AndroidManifest.java:469)
at org.robolectric.manifest.AndroidManifest.getIncludedResourcePaths(AndroidManifest.java:475)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.createAppResourceLoader(RobolectricTestRunner.java:479)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.getAppResourceLoader(RobolectricTestRunner.java:471)
at org.robolectric.internal.ParallelUniverse.setUpApplicationState(ParallelUniverse.java:73)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.setUpApplicationState(RobolectricTestRunner.java:421)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:234)
```

I tried

```
@Config(manifest = "app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml", constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk=21)
```

and I tried setting the manifest location in my TestRunner, nothing worked. In the file system I see that the manifest is in

```
./app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml
```

not in the location Robolectric is looking for it. 
At one point the manifest just got ignored, then a similar issue occurred for resources, the app or Robolectric couldn't find a raw resource my app uses. 
This is in my build file:

```
   sourceSets {
    main {
        java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
    }
    test {
        java.srcDirs = ['src/test/java', 'src/main/java']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src/test/res', 'src/main/res']
    }
}
```

How do I tell Robolectric where to look for a manifest, and more importantly, where to look for resources?

Edit:
I have checked out Robolectric from github, I've built it, installed it in my local .m2 repo, the gradle file now refers to the local SNAPSHOT build, and I made sure Gradle doesn't get a new version from a remote repo. Then I copied the RobolectricGradleTestRunner to my project, I have changed the lines where the file locations are defined: it didn't contain the module name. Now it works.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I'm assuming you're trying to run the tests with JUnit. You can try two different things:

1. Create a Custom TestRunner class, as shown [here](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/triumph-android-studio-1-2-sneaks-in-full-testing-support/). Check the CustomTestRunner section, where you basically create a TestRunner that actually knows the right manifest to use. Specify your tests for them to run with your test runner, with the `@Config` annotation.
2. (My preferred choice) Go the your JUnit configuration, Run > Edit Configurations. Notice the 'Working Directory' textbox. Append `/app` (for OSX and Linux) or `\app` (Windows), to the path written in the textbox. Try running again and it should work.

Comment: This is the new version of the post suggested https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/triumph-android-studio-1-2-sneaks-in-full-testing-support/

Comment: Yes, adding the "app" string turned out to be essential.

Comment: Thank you big time Chaparro!

Comment: Thanks for saving me so much time!

Comment: A better solution is to just set the Working directory to $MODULE_DIR$ as recommended on the Robolectric Getting Started page, http://robolectric.org/getting-started/

Comment: What to do if you're using CI?

Answer (score 66):

Same problem on Android Studio. I've solved this problem to edit the configuration of Unit4. you can follow these things.

On Android Studio.

1. Edit Configurations
2. In Junit, you have to change the working directory to $MODULE_DIR$.

The important thing is **$MODULE_DIR$**.

you can reference the following screenshot. thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is the correct answer.  It is an issue that affects Mac users.  This is actually documented on the Robolectric Getting Started page, http://robolectric.org/getting-started/.

Comment: I'm new in Robolectric; just setup the project and probably did something wrong. Still, this answer resolved my issue on Windows.

Comment: But why AS need it to every new test ? Is it any way to Indicate "Working directory" for all tests?

Comment: I don't know why based on other comments it should work but I can not get it working on AS 3.5. Anyone else facing the same?

Answer (score 10):

In case you are still getting this error with Android Studio 3.0, please be sure that your gradle configuration has these parameters:

```
android {
    ...
    testOptions {
        unitTests {
            includeAndroidResources = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks! That saved my day! I was really struggling with new gradle plugin 3.0.0, gradle 4.1 and Android studio 3. My Robolectric tests went nuts! Now everything is back to normal.

Comment: Thank you. This saved me possibly hours of debugging.

Answer (score 6):

I have faced same errors, We used several flavors and buildtypes
So, there are steps to make it working:

1. Android studio tests run configuration

You have to set working directory to $MODULE_DIR$ in Windows too. http://robolectric.org/getting-started/ should say that.

2. Unit test should be annotated like this:

   @RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
   @Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = 21, manifest = "src/main/AndroidManifest.xml", packageName = "com.example.yourproject")
   public class SomeFragmentTest {

Comment: Make sure you are importing the correct BuildConfig - I wasn't paying attention and pulled BuildConfig from a library which causes a similar issue to the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Note that intellij 16 EAP has a bug around this $MODULE_DIR$ variable (it's pointing to the wrong place), causing the tests to fail with this exception. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-149802#tab=History. Should get fixed mid Jan 2016.

Answer (score 2):

Please find the below steps which resolves all the issues.
Step 1: use the version in dependencies

```
testImplementation"org.robolectric:robolectric:4.0" in app.gradle
```

step 2: In app.gradle inside android use below

```
testOptions {    
    unitTests {    
        includeAndroidResources = true      
    }    
}
```

step 3:in gradle.properties paste the below

```
enableUnitTestBinaryResources=true
```

It works !!!

Answer (score 1):

You Can refer the same issue here:https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1648

You should mention this in your test code:

```
@Config(manifest = "src/main/AndroidManifest.xml", emulateSdk = 18)
```

This tells the robolectric where your manifest file is. This should work unless you change your directory values.

also try to use the template available on the internet.Everything is setup in there.You don't need to change your directory values. You can get it from here:https://github.com/robolectric/deckard-gradle

Edit: The way i see is the exception occurs at  "`build/intermediates/bundles/debug/AndroidManifest.xml "`    but you are saying the file is at `"app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml"`,I guess these two are different locations. Please make sure you have the xml file at `build/intermediates/bundles/debug/AndroidManifest.xml "`

Comment: I did. Didn't work. Also, in Robolectric RC3 it's "sdk=18", not "emulateSdk=18".

Comment: I don't put the xml file in the build directory. The build process does that.

Answer (score 0):

That's correct @Christine. I am also facing the exact problem. And the thing is build process is not creating bundles folder at all under intermediates. And custom robolectric runner also didn't work. Here is the custom [runner](https://github.com/nenick/AndroidStudioAndRobolectric/blob/master/app/src/test/java/com/example/myapplication/CustomRobolectricRunner.) I
used. I haven't still figured out the solution but it seems that the problem may be related to build tool version that needs to used.

[Update] Changing working directory in my unit test run configuration to point to the module root directory which is being tested worked for me.[Update]

Answer (score 0):

I had this error after I updated AndroidStudio to 2.3.3 and my gradle plugin was updated too.
It was solved by setting `working directory` to `$MODULE_DIR$` and also updating `robolectric` dependency from `testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0'` to `testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.4.2'`.

Note that setting `working directory` while `robolectric` version is old  won't resolve it.