# Using Roboletric for Junit testing

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit4, robolectric

No such manifest file: build/intermediates/bundles/debug/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

Refered to -[Robolectric says "AndroidManifest.xml not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30913522/robolectric-says-androidmanifest-xml-not-found)

https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1648 but was not helpful.

Comment: Where did you put your tests class ? could you print your project structure please ?

Comment: My test class is written in app/src/test/java/com.packagename/MainActivityTest.

Answer (score 1):

Check your gradle and your class :

Gradle :

```
 testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.3'
 testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
 testCompile 'org.assertj:assertj-core:1.7.1'
```

In your test Class :

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = 25)
public class YourTest {

    @Test
    public void shouldNotBeNull() throws Exception {
       //put your test here for example
    }
)
```

**YourTest class should be put in Test folder (not AndroidTest folder)**

On Android Studio :

- Edit Configurations
- In Junit, you have to change the working directory to $MODULE_DIR$.
  The important thing is $MODULE_DIR$.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the **No such manifest file: ./AndroidManifest.xml** warning, by updating your gradle file.

Add the following line to your gradle file to so that the correct Android manifest is used. The includeAndroidResources option allows you to access android resources in your unit tests, including your AndroidManifest file.
app/build.gradle

```
testOptions.unitTests {
    includeAndroidResources = true
}
```

src: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/advanced-android-kotlin-training-testing-basics/index.html?index=..%2F..index#7